# lifting loops on surface with abelian fundamental group for decrease their self-intersection number

Tags: algebraic-topology, surfaces, fundamental-groups

I found a proof of following statement (which is available [here](http://www.math.rice.edu/~andyp/papers/SelfIntersections.pdf) ), but I'm not sure if we must assume that fundamental group of surface $M$ is non-abelian:

**Lemma**: Let $M$ be a compact orientable surface (possibly bounded) with $\pi_1(M)$ non-abelian and let $f: S^1 \to M$ be a non-nullhomotopic closed curve. Then there exists a degree 8 normal cover $M \to \tilde{M}$ such that one of the following holds.

- $f$ does not lift to a closed curve on $\tilde{M}$.
- $f$ lifts to a closed curve $\tilde{f}: S^1 → \tilde{M}$ with $i( \tilde{f}) < i( f )$.

where $i(f)$ is self-intersection number of the loop 
(minimum over all curves $f'$ which are freely homotopic to $f$ of the
quantity $|\{(x,y)\mid x,y \in S^1, x \neq y, f'(x)=f'(y) \} |/2$)

**So, the question is: Is this lemma is true for surfaces with abelian fundamental group?**

Comment: There's only one compact orientable surface (without boundary) with abelian fundamental group. So you need only verify or disprove this for the torus.

Comment: this surface can have boundary, but yes there are not many kinds of surfaces to check.

Comment: Orientable surfaces with non-empty boundary have free fundamental group on more than one generator (except for the sphere which is trivial) so the torus really is the only example.

Comment: So I think only examples are torus and sphere with two boundary components. right?
Now I still don't know is this lemma is true without assumption of non-abelian fundamental group.